# How to fix "<TModel>.Model.get returned null" in MVC app?

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I'm doing this app with a login view and I have a User model that has Username and Password to fill in at the login (as regular). I get this eror at the using statement in the view:

```
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null.
```

Before I had this implemented but I changed it because I'm using a sample template that uses inputs and spans instead of labelfor and editfor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Authorise", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td style="text-decoration:underline"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <label class="field-validation-error">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LoginMessage)</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                    <td><input type="reset" value="Clean" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
```

Before the change everything was working fine.
I changed the view to this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Authorise", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <form class="login100-form validate-form">
                    <span class="login100-form-logo">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-landscape"></i>
                    </span>

                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34 p-t-27">
                        Log in
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter username">

                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" value="@Model.Username">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" value="@Model.Password">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="contact100-form-checkbox">
                        <input class="input-checkbox100" id="ckb1" type="checkbox" name="remember-me">
                        <label class="label-checkbox100" for="ckb1">
                            Remember me
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn">
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center p-t-90">
                        <a class="txt1" href="#">
                            Forgot Password?
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (FITMEContext db = new FITMEContext())
        {

        }

        return View();
    }

    //For login
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Authorise(User user)
    {
        using (FITMEContext db = new FITMEContext())
        {
            var userDetail = db.Users.Where(x => x.Username == user.Username && x.Password == user.Password).FirstOrDefault();

            if (userDetail == null)
            {
                user.LoginMessage = "Invalid username or password";
                return View("Index", user);
            }
            else
            {
                Session["UserId"] = user.UserId;
                Session["UserName"] = user.Username;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }            
    }
```

Model:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("User name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill in the user name")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill in the password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string LoginMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the entire exception stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the "Index" method you're calling View() without arguments. That's why Model == null

One of possible solutions is to create default model object and pass it to the view:

```
return View("Index", new User())
```

Comment: Hi @EvheniyLoginov, welcome to SO. Nice comment and I think this might be the problem. Now, where is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

The helper method `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)` would have been checking if Model is null before trying to access it. Now that you are rendering the values yourself, instead of with the helper methods, you will need to explicitly add null checks.

```
<input class="input100" type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" value="@(Model == null ? "" : Model.Username)">
```

As an alternative, you can still use the helper methods and specify the class of the input:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { @class = "input100" })
```

Comment: I don't know if it is working because when I click the login button the page refreshes

Comment: Then put a breakpoint in the `Authorise()` method and step through to see what's actually happening

Answer (score 0):

I now have changed to this below but the submit button just refreshes the page I don't know why. It was working in the other layout. Any tip on this? Seems an easy fix

```
<div class="wrap-login100">
            <form class="login100-form validate-form">
                <span class="login100-form-logo">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-landscape"></i>
                </span>

                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34 p-t-27">
                    Log in
                </span>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter username">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" value="@(Model == null ? "" : Model.Username)" />
                    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" value="@(Model == null ? "" : Model.Password)" />
                    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="contact100-form-checkbox">
                    <input class="input-checkbox100" id="ckb1" type="checkbox" name="remember-me">
                    <label class="label-checkbox100" for="ckb1">
                        Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>

                @*<div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn">
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>*@

                <input type="submit" value="Login" />

                <div class="text-center p-t-90">
                    <a class="txt1" href="#">
                        Forgot Password?
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```